# issue with applicationcontext.xml file

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I am using Struts 2, Hibernate and Spring in Eclipse. I have issues with the location of `applicationcontext.xml` file. While creating a bean, my application shows an error that `applicationcontext.xml` cannot be found. The file was in `webcontent/WEB-INF`. Then I copied it to the `src` folder, and now it works. However if I cut it from the `WEB-INF` folder, even the welcome file is not loading. I have to keep two copies of `applicationcontext.xml` in order for the application to work properly. How can I solve this issue?